# Executing build-in functions from VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, evaluate

I need to have a capability to execute any kind of build-in functions (such as 'sum' or 'len') from VBA (MS Excel).

One of the restrictions that I have is that I may not pass cell ranges as arguments to these functions. Instead of this, I should be able to use strict values.

I want to be able to use the following expression SUM(1, 2) which should return 3, while the following version SUM("A1:A2") won't work for me.

I managed to develop some function that parses my prior input and makes it consist of a list of values (as for example above, it made the user's input of 'A1:A2' look like an array of numbers consisting of two values).

So, can anyone give me an example of using a build-in function that receives a list of values (not just range of cells)?

I tried the following code, but for some unknown reason, I haven't been able to get it working (I keep getting 1004 error, saying: Cannot run the macro 'SUM'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.):

```
Application.Run "SUM", 2, 2
```

Some valuable advices that would help to find a solution to this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Some valuable advices that would help ....` There is a magical key in Excel. Surprisingly you can press it from Worksheet and from the VBA Editor :) The key is `F1`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Pushing F1 in the macro editor just takes you to a webpage saying that F1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

To use a built-in, Excel, Worksheet function, you need to do something like the following:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(2,2)
```

Comment: ok, what do you say me if I say that function name and argument client send me from other side? My client, can send me function name as string and argument for function as range or array. Ok, I can use reflection but I`m not sure that all function realize in the WorksheetFunction. And f.e. what I should do if smb send me function "Len"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean but we seem to have addressed your original question.